# pathname of each image in javascript array

Tags: javascript, php

I have written a simple code to navigate an image folder. It's for a web comic site so each image is displayed alone and then next and previous buttons cycle through the available content.

My problem is that the image number doesn't show in the URL so you can't link to an individual comic which makes sharing, RSS etc rather ineffectual.

I don't know if I need try getting the path to show up using PHP or if it can be added as a variable to my existing Javascript or if the script needs to be embedded in the index page itself. I've been researching this for hours, I think location.path may be the key but I haven't been able to work out how to successfully implement it.

```
var images = ["comic_imgs/1.jpg",
    "comic_imgs/2.jpg",
    "comic_imgs/3.jpg",
    "comic_imgs/4.jpg",
    "comic_imgs/5.jpg",
];
var index = 4;

function nextImage()
{
    ++index;
    if (index < images.length)
    {
        document.getElementById("ID").setAttribute("src", images[index]);
    }
    else
    {
        index = (images.length - 1);
        nextImage();
    }
}

function previousImage()
{
    --index;
    if (index > -1)
    {
        document.getElementById("ID").setAttribute("src", images[index]);
    }
    else
    {
        index = 1;
        previousImage();
    }
}

function firstImage()
{
    index = 0;
    document.getElementById("ID").setAttribute("src", images[index]);
}

function lastImage()
{
    index = (images.length - 1);
    document.getElementById("ID").setAttribute("src", images[index]);
}
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is changing the src for the #ID element.

If for example this is your HTML:

`<img src='[url]' id='ID'/>`

You can encapsulate your img with A tag, as this will allow users to have a link to the given image:

`<a href='[url]'><img src='[url]' id='ID'/></a>`

Then (to make the href change when you change the src) you'll only need to add:

`document.getElementById("ID").parentNode.setAttribute("href", images[index]);` everywhere you're doing `document.getElementById("ID").setAttribute("src", images[index]);`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that out tonight!

Comment: Hello, I tried this out but it isn't quite what I was looking for. I need the path to show up in the url in the browser so it would ideally become 'mysite/index/comic/number.ext. I'm not sure if this is achievable with the script I'm using and if it isn't, I can just implement gallery software. I'd just rather try and adapt the current code. And I suspect the name I gave this thread may be misleading.

Comment: What you're looking for then (as well) is manual URL change (if user clicks on link, the URL at the top changes, but he stays on the same page, all JS actions proceed as currently). To do that, I'd suggest looking at https://github.com/browserstate/history.js, which is intended to do that

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll look into that shortly.